# How do I build the images locally before deploying remotely via docker-compose so I don't have to send a big build context over the internet?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been deploying remotely with `docker-compose -H $docker_host up --build`, but the directory is large and even though I only need 2 small binaries for the images everything is getting sent to the remote server.

The slowness is having an impact on my performance, so I was wondering if there was a way to make compose build the images locally and then send *those* instead of the whole directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .dockerignore file tells docker what files to ignore when sending the build context during a docker build.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great solution!

Comment: It's great! Sending the build context went down from ~8 minutes to ~2 seconds! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* build the images locally, but you will need a Docker daemon to do that. After building an image you would then push it to a Docker registry (you could also use a public registry, like the [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com) and then you could download the image from that registry on the target server.

You can head over to the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#docker-architecture) to learn more about the architecture or ask a more specific question - I'll try to answer.